# IText Sharp strange issue with Twitter Bootstrap CSS 3.3.6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, itext

I am trying to render a HTML with ITextSharp.
Getting HTML is good, getting CSS works but, I have a strange issue with the CSS from Boostrap 3.3.6.

The whole content of the page disappear from the PDF if there is the following line :
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 
{float: left;}

It seems that ITextSharp CSS analyzer have a problem with "float: left"

Is there a solution or a hack to make it work properly ?